# Organisational File Repository

Tags: google-drive-api

We are trying to establish Google Drive as a file share. Its a read-only repository of reference material used by workers.  The files can be read by anyone even by outsiders who do  not work here.

We use the Google Drive API to set up links for the files to appear on our website. The problem we have is users need to be authenticated with Google first when they open this page.  The API looks for a user signed with Google before allowing to obtain a list of files. Among other issues this is not practical because some prefer not to use their personal Google logins to access work material.

The files will be publicly shared anyway. Will OAuth 2.0 read only authorise without authentication if the files are public?

Answer (score 1):

Making API requests always requires authorization, for quota, etc.

However, you could easily download a file and serve it, or you can use the `webContentLink` of a resource to allow the user to open it in a browser.

Comment: Thank you I suspect you are thinking of a sample such as this > http://dannyruijters.nl/webtexit/googledrive.html  Even to get webContentLink, you need to be signed into Google don't you?

Answer (score 0):

What Ali is saying is that you can be the administrator with Google drive access and create a file in your drive and part of the metadata you get back from Google is the webContentLink which can be accessed by anyone even those without Google credentials.